# C# - LINQ mutual exclusive elements

Tags: c#, linq

I have a task which I think can be solved with LINQ. The problem is I am pretty new with it and I just can't implement my idea correctly.

**Problem:**
I have two string lists:

```
 var list1 = new List<string>{ "item1", "item2" }; <br>
 var list2 = new List<string>{ "item1", "item3", "item3", "item4" };
```

The goal is to return a new List containing the elements from list2 which are **not** contained in list1, ( "item3", "item4" )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, it is a simple one:

```
list2.Except(list1).ToList();
```

The trailing `ToList` is present because you said you *goal is to return a new List* - but if all you'll do is e.g. enumerate the result with a foreach or something, it can be omitted

Good spot from juharr; your first duplicated item3 was right on the word wrap boundary on the mobile site so I didn't notice your list was 1,3,3,4

A poorly performing variant that keeps duplicates, ok for small lists:

```
list2.Where(e => !list1.Contains(e));
```

A better performing version that should be used for large list1:

```
var lookup = new HashSet<string>(list1);
list2.Where(e => !lookup.Contains(e));
```

Comment: omg, I swear I was aboutto reinvent the wheel

Comment: @GicuMironica Note this will also remove duplicates.  So for the example you'll only get "item3" once.